# Android AccountManager needs gmail id or can be used other type?

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have a confusion while working with AccountManager in Android. Is it required only gmail id when we authenticate the user at first time?

I didn't get any docs who says it requres gmail id only, but during my RnD I got many tutorials and all are using gmail id, So I am confused.

***Can I used other type of IDs to authenticate the user?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a necessity:

"Different online services have different ways of handling accounts and authentication, so the account manager uses pluggable authenticator modules for different account types. Authenticators (which may be written by third parties) handle the actual details of validating account credentials and storing account information. For example, Google, Facebook, and Microsoft Exchange each have their own authenticator."

Very well explained in detail here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html